# Barplots with Tikz and PGFPLOTS

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, bar-chart

I'm new to LaTeX. I'm trying to create a bar plot with beamer document class. Here is what I need:

[image]

Here is what I get in LaTeX:

[image]

Please see below for MWE:

Here are my questions:

1. How can I replicate the above chart, similar looking in LaTeX ? I like to retain the tik marks and the out borders. I'm more interested in the X axis label and separation of the bars.
2. How do I adjust the width of the chart with similar aspect ratio
   just to this chart (as I have several charts, I do not want give
   global options) and also the width of the bar to chart above?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
                \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[ybar=25pt,ymin=0,ymax=150,]
                
                    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue, area legend] coordinates {(Rat,40)};
                    \addplot[ybar,fill=red, area legend] coordinates {(Hippopotamus,146)};
                
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. This follows: [PGFPLOTS - Create Bar plot with bars in different colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370552/). See the code for the various changes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
         ybar,
         xmin=0.5,xmax=2.5, %<-- added
         ymin=0,
         ymax=150,
         area legend,
         xtick={1,2}, % <-- added
         xticklabels={Rat,Hippopotamus}, % <-- added
         every axis plot/.append style={ % <-- added
          bar width=.5,
          bar shift=0pt,
          fill} 
         ]
         \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {(1,40)};
         \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {(2,146)};
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```